# C++ : Arrays and memory locations

Tags: c++, arrays

Array of characters has always managed to intrigue me.

Lets create an array of integer type-

```
int a[]={1,2,34};
cout<<a;
```

in this case `cout<<a` gives us the location of the array `a`

But-

```
char a[]="C++";
cout<<a;
```

gives us `C++`as the display , it is quite interesting.

**1)** So why doesnt the array of characters show its memory location when used with cout?

**2)** How can I find the location of an array of characters?

All help would be appreciated :)

*- Newbie in C++ with a will to learn*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"1) So why doesnt the array of characters show its memory location when used with cout?"*

There's a specialized overload for

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);
```

that's why you always see the characters printed, not the address.

> *"2) How can I find the location of an array of characters?"*

You can cast to a `void*` pointer if you want to see the address of the `char` array:

```
char a[]="C++";
cout << (void*)a;
```

or just prefix the address operator as [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) suggested in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459598/c-arrays-and-memory-locations/27459633?noredirect=1#comment43355964_27459633)

```
cout << &a;
```

Comment: Fwiw, `std::cout << &a;` will work, as there is no overload for any flavor of pointer-to-pointer I'm aware of, and no cast is required.

Comment: @ravi That was written that way intentionally!

Answer (score 0):

Below are two overloads of operator<< available in standard:-

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);  // _1
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, void*);  //       _2

int arr[] = {1,2,3};
cout << arr;             // This would invoke _2

char arr[] = "Hello";
cout << arr;             // This would invoke _1

char arr[] = "Hello";
cout << (void*)arr;      // This would invoke _2
cout << &arr;
```

Hope I'm clear

Answer (score 0):

First of all rake into account that there is not `operator <<` for integer arrays.

When you write statements like these

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 34 };
cout << a;
```

then expression `a` is implicitly converted to a pointer of type `const void *` that to select the following overloaded operator

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(const void* p);
```

As for character arrays then the C++ Standard explicitly defines overloaded `operator <<` for type `const char *`

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&,
const char*);
```

If you want that for character arrays would be called the `operator <<` that is defined for type `const void *` then you have to explicitly cast the pointer to thjis type. For example

```
char a[] = "C++";
cout << static_cast<const void *>( a );
```